# Show $(1+\frac{z}{n})^{n} \underset{n \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow }e^{z}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, mathematical-french

> To show that $$z_n=\left(1+\dfrac{z}{n} \right)^{n} \underset{n \longmapsto +\infty}{\longrightarrow \exp(z)}$$
>   the author of textbook use the following method but there is some steps that i'm not sure if i got it right so would someone elaborate it

Let $x = \Re(z)$ and $y=\Im(z)$

- ${\displaystyle r_n=\sqrt{\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n} \right)^{2}+\dfrac{y^{2}}{n^2}}=\sqrt{1+\dfrac{2x}{n}+o\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)}=1+\dfrac{x}{n}+o\left(\dfrac{x}{n}\right)}$
- why if $r_n=1+\dfrac{x}{n}+o\left(\dfrac{x}{n} \right)$ then $\ln(r_n)\sim \dfrac{x}{n}$
- how we can get the expression of $\tan(\alpha_n)$
- why if $\tan\left( \alpha_n \right)\sim \dfrac{y}{n}$ then $\alpha_{n}\sim \dfrac{y}{n}$

[image]

My thoughts:

first i think there is typo in $z_n=r_n^{n}e^{n\alpha_n}$ should we write $z_n=r_n^{n}e^{i n\alpha_n}$ instead.

- ${\displaystyle r_n=\sqrt{\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}
     \right)^{2}+\dfrac{y^{2}}{n^2}}=\sqrt{1+\dfrac{2x}{n}+o\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)}=1+\dfrac{x}{n}+o\left(\dfrac{x}{n}\right)}$

note that

> $$\left(1+x \right)^{\alpha}\underset{x\to 0}{=}1+\alpha x +o\left( x\right) $$

$$\begin{cases} \left(1+\dfrac{x}{n} \right)^{2}=1+2\dfrac{x}{n}+o\left( \dfrac{1}{n}\right) \\ \dfrac{y^{2}}{n^{2}}=o\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\end{cases}\implies 1+\dfrac{2x}{n}+o\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$$

on the other hand 
\begin{aligned}\sqrt{1+\dfrac{2x}{n}+o\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)}=\left(1+\dfrac{2x}{n}+o\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right) \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}&=1+\dfrac{1}{2}\left( \dfrac{2x}{n}+o\left( \dfrac{1}{n}\right)\right)+o\left(o\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\right) \\
&=1+\dfrac{x}{n}+o\left( \dfrac{1}{n}\right)+o\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\\
&=1+\dfrac{x}{n}+o\left( \dfrac{1}{n}\right)
\end{aligned}
then $$\fbox{$r_{n}=1+\dfrac{x}{n}+o\left( \dfrac{1}{n}\right)$}$$

- why if $r_n=1+\dfrac{x}{n}+o\left(\dfrac{x}{n} \right)$ then $\ln(r_n)\sim \dfrac{x}{n}$

note that :

> if $u_n\sim v_n $ and $v_n \sim w_n $ then $u_n \sim w_n$ 
>   $u_n\sim v_n \iff u_n=v_n+o(v_n)$

i can't show this

- how we can get the expression of $\tan(\alpha_n)$

> If $a+ib=\rho e^{i\theta}$ with  $a>0$  then $\tan(\theta)=\frac b a$

since $\left( 1+\dfrac{z}{n}\right)=\left( 1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)+i\dfrac{y}{n}=r_{n}e^{i\alpha_n} $ then 
$$\tan(\alpha_n)=\dfrac{\dfrac{y}{n}}{1+\dfrac{x}{n}}=\dfrac{y}{x+n}$$
$$\fbox{$\tan(\alpha_n)=\dfrac{y}{x+n} $} $$

- why if $\tan\left( \alpha_n \right)\sim \dfrac{y}{n}$ then $\alpha_{n}\sim \dfrac{y}{n}$

> if $u_n\sim v_n $ and $v_n \sim w_n $ then $u_n \sim w_n$

So should show that $\alpha_n \underset{n \to +\infty}{\overset{}{\longrightarrow}}0$ to be able to say that $\tan(\alpha_n)\sim r_n$

we've $\tan(\alpha_n)=\dfrac{y}{x+n}$ then $\alpha_n=\arctan\left(\dfrac{y}{x+n}\right) $
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\alpha_n=\lim_{n\to +\infty} \arctan\left(\dfrac{y}{x+n}\right)=\arctan\left(\dfrac{y}{x+\lim_{n\to +\infty} n}\right)=\arctan(0)=0   $$
then $$\begin{cases}\tan(\alpha_n) \sim \alpha_n  \\  \tan(\alpha_n)\sim \dfrac{y}{n} \end{cases} \implies \alpha_n\sim \dfrac{y}{n}$$

- If my proof wrong would you elaborate the steps

Comment: what is your definition for $\mathrm{e}^z$? Is it $\exp(z)$ or $\exp(1)^z$ or $\Big[\lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\big(1+\frac{1}{n}\big)^n\Big]^z$?
And it would be nice if you had mention that $x = \Re(z)$ and $y=\Im(z)$

Comment: okay i have added them

Answer (score 1):

This is a very strange proof, apart from the handwaving colloquial style in printed matter. The usual  setup is the following:
$$\eqalign{e^z-\left(1+{z\over n}\right)^n&=\bigl((e^{z/n}\bigr)^n-\left(1+{z\over n}\right)^n\cr
&=\left(e^{z/n}-\bigl(1+{z\over n}\bigr)\right)\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\bigl(e^{z/n}\bigr)^{n-1-k}\left(1+{z\over n}\right)^k\cr
&=R_n\cdot \Sigma_n\ .\cr}$$
Here
$$R_n={z^2\over n^2}g\left({z\over n}\right)$$
with $\lim_{\zeta\to0}g(\zeta)={1\over2}$ by Taylor's theorem, and
$$\eqalign{|\Sigma_n|&\leq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\bigl(e^{|z|/n}\bigr)^{n-1-k}\left(1+{|z|\over n}\right)^k\leq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\bigl(e^{|z|/n}\bigr)^{n-1-k}\left(1+{|z|\over n}\right)^k\cr &\leq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\bigl(e^{|z|/n}\bigr)^{n-1-k}\bigl(e^{|z|/n}\bigr)^k\leq n\>e^{|z|}\ .\cr}$$